# Go string appears shorter than it's first rune

Tags: string, go, rune

I was running some fuzzing on my code and it found a bug. I have reduced it down to the following code snippet and I cannot see what is wrong.

Given the string

```
s := string("\xc0")
```

The `len(s)` function returns `1`. However, if you loop through the string the first rune is length 3.

```
    for _, r := range s {
        fmt.Println("len of rune:", utf8.RuneLen(r)) // Will print 3
    }
```

My assumptions are:

- `len(string)` is returning the number of bytes in the string
- `utf8.RuneLen(r)` is returning the number of bytes in the rune

I assume I am misunderstanding something, but how can the length of a string be less than the length of one of it's runes?

Playground here: https://go.dev/play/p/SH3ZI2IZyrL

Comment: `"\xc0"` isn't a valid utf8 character, so if you were to print the value you would see the unicode replacement character. The value of a single unicode replacement character (`0xfffd`) requires 3 bytes (`0xef` `0xbf` `0xbd`) to encode as `utf8`. (also note the `RuneLen` docs, which does _not_ return the number of bytes in the rune, rather it returns the number of bytes required to utf8 encode the rune)

Comment: `for _, r := range s` doesn't do what you think it does. Ask yourself: Is `s` a valid UTF-8 encoded string? What if not? What will `r` be according to the spec?

Comment: Or, to answer the title: Your string doesn't contain any runes.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, I thought to check that and `utf8.ValidRune(r)` returns `true` so I assumed it would be a valid character. Is there a better way to check validity?

Comment: Thanks @Volker, I've realised that using `utf8.ValidString()` before the loop was the right way to check and not `utf8.ValidRune(r)` on each rune. That has unstuck me!

Comment: @DanielWhitford, your example already attempts to decode the bytes, at which point you are only checking if the replacement character is valid. If you want to know if the bytes are valid, use `utf8.Valid` or `utf8.ValidString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is simple: your input is not valid UTF-8 encoded string.

```
fmt.Println(utf8.ValidString(s))
```

This outputs: `false`.

The `for range` over a `string` ranges over its runes, but if an invalid UTF-8 sequence is encountered, the Unicode replacement character `0xFFFD` is set for `r`. [Spec: For statements:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_statements)

> For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code points in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and the second value, of type rune, will be the value of the corresponding code point. If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the second value will be `0xFFFD`, the Unicode replacement character, and the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.

This applies to your case: you get `0xfffd` for `r` which has 3 bytes using UTF-8 encoding.

If you go with a valid string holding a `rune` of `\xc0`:

```
s = string([]rune{'\xc0'})
```

Then output is:

```
len of s: 2
runes in s: 1
len of rune: 2
UTF-8 bytes of s: [195 128]
Hexa UTF-8 bytes of s: c3 80
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/y8x73W6Iul3).

Comment: Info: All bytes with the high bit set (`\80` .. `\xFF) are part of a multibyte sequence for one rune.